# dificuldade com relacionamento de tabelas de pagamento

Tags: tabela-banco-de-dados, pagamento-online

Estou com dificuldade para criar tabelas no banco de dados para trabalhar com pagamento, estou criando a tabela pagamento com o valor do pagamento total e outras tabelas de dinheiro,promissoria,cheque,boleto,cartao e bemmaterial, cada uma com o id da tabela pagamento. alguém pode me ajudar no relacionamento entre estas tabelas e se pode estar certo ou errado. 
Como ficaria em relacao o cancelamento de um produto dentro de uma compra para referenciar algum pagamento feito

Imagem das tabelas em anexo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: jamais faria várias tabelas assim... tudo é movimento financeiro, tudo tem data, valor, uma pessoa relacionada, etc.... e se o cliente quer receber pagamentos por serviço online (picpay, paypal, etc...) mais tabelas ? e na hora de somar isso tudo... quantos `unions` vai precisar ? simplifique ao máximo, rs

Comment: Se eu criar uma tabela somente de pagamento e especificar a forma de pagamento se seria dinheiro, cartao,promissoria etc. Se for desta forma como seria criar 3 vias de promissorias ou boleto, teria que duplicar os dados ?

Comment: 3 vias ? acredito que vias você imprima quantas quiser...mas só armazena uma, se está se referindo à parcelas, cada parcela é um movimento diferente, tendo datas diferentes, e até mesmo valores diferentes.

Comment: mas precisaria armazenar as datas diferentes destas vias(neste caso, parcelas), talvez valores diferentes tambem, dai como faria isso, outra tabela pra armazenar essas parcelas com data e valor e o id do pagamento?

Comment: Cada parcela, é um movimento diferente, vou elaborar uma resposta e  coloco tentando explicar melhor

Comment: posso estar equivocado mas criando desta forma de tabelas que apresentei eu poderia inserir quantos valores eu quisesse em formas de pagamentos diferentes referenciadas a um so pagamento (MAS O PROBLEMA SURGE PORQUE ELAS FICAM DEPENDENTES DESTE PAGAMENTO PARA EXISTIR?, por exemplo o cheque pode ir de um lugar para outro)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63554/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-luciano).